# Homeomorphism from the suspension of $S^{n-1}$ to $S^n$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $S(X) = (X \times [-1,1])/R$ denote the suspension of $X$, where the classes of $R$ are $X \times \{1\}, X \times \{-1\}$ and all singletons $\{a\}$, where $a \in X \times (-1,1)$. Show that $S(S^{n-1})$ is homeomorphic to $S^n$. (Don’t confuse $S$ and $S^n$, $S$ is the suspension and $S^n$ is the unit sphere).

So I want to find an cont bijection with continuous inverse $f:S(S^{n-1}) \to S^n$ and since every output of $f$ must be of length one I’m thinking about $f(x) = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ which would satisfy the conditions of homeomorphism, but I’m not sure if this works? Also should is it neccessarily defined in all of $S(S^{n-1})$? I don’t think $S(S^{n-1})$ contains $\vec{0}$?

Comment: A picture for $n=1$ case which might give you intuition as to why this holds: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2700985/4280), e.g.

Comment: Take two distinct points $p,q$ in $S^{n-1}$. Your idea $f$ would send $(p,1)$ and $(q,1)$ to different values, while they're the same point in the suspension. So not well-defined.

Comment: You should explain what you are missing in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $f(\vec{x}, t) = (\sqrt{1-t^2}\cdot \vec{x}, t)$ is well-defined from $\Bbb S^{n-1} \times [-1,1]$ to $S^n$, where $\vec{x}$ is an $n$-dimensional real vector, and clearly continuous.

$f(\vec{x},t)=f(\vec{y},t')$ iff $t=1$ or $t=-1$ or else $t \in (-1,1)$ and $\vec{x}=\vec{y}$, as can be easily verified. So the unique map $g: S(S^{n-1}) \to S^n$ that obeys $g \circ q= f$ (where $q: \Bbb S^{n-1} \times [-1,1] \to S(S^{n-1})$ is the suspension quotient) is bijective and continuous and by compactness is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure I entirely understood where the first coordinate of the output of $f$ came from? Also is there a reason why $x \mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ doesn’t work?

Comment: @Wondera compute the norm of the image vector (in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$) and see why we need the square root factor, there is no choice... Your map idea doesn't work well with the quotient construction.

Comment: can you please clarify what is the equivalence relation of the map q?

Comment: can you please explain how the injectivity of the map f is still valid $t \neq t'$? Or this case can not happen? ..... Also when you said at $t =1$ you mean automatically that $t'$ will be equal 1?

Comment: can you please clarify what the square root of $1 - t^2$ is doing to the first nth coordinates? Why you multiplied by it?